# SQL query performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I am writing a script to migrate my users table.
So basically, I've 3 db tables : events, users, newusers. The users table is meant to be replaced by the newusers table and will be dropped later. The newusers table has a column with the oldusers id (PK) value.

The events2 table has 2 FKs : 1 for users, 1 for newusers. 
I've already written the part that migrates records users to new users, where I am struggling is to update the FK in the events 2 table.

I've written the following:

```
update events2
 set newusersid = newuser.id
 from events2 e
 inner join newusers newuser on newuser.olduserid = e.userid;
```

but it takes very long time to execute. Is there an improved way

One of the reason for the migration is that we wanted to change the id value in the newusers table so I can't re-use the same PK values for the corresponding users records.

thanks for your help

N.

Comment: You may need to add a temporary index on `olduserid`, and drop it after you are finished your upgrade.

Comment: What's "a very long time?"  This is a one-time operation - does it need to be fast?

Comment: @marc_s I am using postgresql 8.4

Comment: @Dan Puzey it takes 1 hour for ~65k records in both tables

Comment: @Blazes I'll try that an let you know

Comment: 1 hour for ~65k records? Sounds like a lock, check pg_locks. Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an index on the newuser table with the olduserid and the userId in that order? That should speed the query up quite a bit.

Related, if you are updating millions of rows in the events table, you will hit a limit as far as how quickly the query can perform.

Comment: And do you have an index on `newuser.olduserid` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems wrong. Shouldn't it be the following?

```
update events2
set newusersid = newuser.id
from newusers newuser
where newuser.olduserid = events2.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have an `INDEX` on events2.userid and newusers.olduserid
2. You can try using a `SELECT INTO` query, not sure the performance impact

*More information is needed about your database, tables, and hardware.*

Comment: Thanks for the tips, pardon my ignorance, I have to update existing records in events2 I don't know how to use a select into in this case.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I assumed you created `events2` with a SELECT INTO, or an INSERT INTO.  Instead of doing that and then the update, I was saying do the update at the time of `events2` creation.